# I need a constant and unified solution to stream audio in Android and IOS web browsers

Tags: android, ios, audio, streaming

I need a constant and unified solution to stream audio in Android and IOS web browsers.
Actually, I have it in flash based but I want something for mobile web browsers instead of flash.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the HTML5 audio-tag? More info on it here: http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

That site also has a compatibility list for browsers and codecs and has been updated relatively recently.

Comment: There are incompatibility support for file formats between different web browsers and html5 in different platforms. Flash integrates all the platforms except for IOS & safari. I need to decrease development cost and time by an integrated solution just in a web page. Any idea? Is there any project undergoing to cure this problem?